# Finding Elements

Tags: jquery, html

Can anyone help. Im trying to select some elements on a form but as the elements are being dynmaically added this is starting to cause problems.

The element(s) I need to select is the second input element within each child div.
Ive been trying something along the lines of this (without much luck):

```
$("#parentdiv :input:first-child").addClass("bad")
```

Thanks,

Comment: If it's the second input element, pretty sure you don't want to use `first-child`. And you could just try doing `$($("#parent input")[1]).addClass("bad")`. Gets you the second input every time.

Comment: That would select only the second element in the whole set, not the second element for each parent. Showing us your DOM structure would be a good idea by the way.

Comment: The original post would also only select the first element in the whole set (the first comment is closer to the answer). What you want to do is to set a class on all containing divs, then select the 2nd input in each div using `$(".containing-div :input:nth-child(2)").addClass("bad")`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$('#parentdiv :input:nth-child(2)').addClass("bad")
```

Comment: This is actually slightly wrong in that it will only select the 2nd child of `#parentdiv` and apparently (according to http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) all other children are counted whereas `:eq(1)` only counts elements matching the attached selector. One improvement would be to use a class instead of `#parentdiv`, although it could be `#parentdiv .containing-div :input:eq(1)`.